A ring R is non-singular on the right then R has no total divisors of zero on the right?
Is true that if a not unitary ring R is non-singular on the right then R has no total divisors of zero on the right?
Obviously it is easy to prove that if R is non-singular on the right then R has no total divisors of zero on the left. But I do not have idea how to show the first case.

A total right divisor of zero is a non zero element a in R and Ra=0
